# Determinant Formula for Tri-Diagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

for an assignment in numerical analysis, I need to find the eigenvalues of a matrix with values only in the diagonal, upper diagonal and lower diagonal. I guess there is an easy formula for this sort of Matrices, Specifically if all the values are similar.

If not in the general, so specifically:

$A(jj) = 1-k$, $A(j-1, j ) = A(j, j-1) = A(1,N) = A(N,1) = k$  $\forall j \in \{ 1 ... N\} $

Comment: What is your question?  [How to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959)

Comment: I think the question is clear enough. May be the OP did not know how to typeset a matrix, but the information is all there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is circulant (not tri-diagonal). If we write 
$$
T=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
0&1&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&1&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&0&1&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&1\\
1&0&0&0&\cdots&0
\end{array}\right)
$$
for the matrix with ones one step above the diagonal and at bottom left, and zeros elsewhere, then your matrix is
$$
A=(1-k)I+kT+kT^{N-1},
$$
where we can, if we so desire, us $T^{-1}$ in place of $T^{N-1}$, as $T^N=I$.

A general circulant matrix would be one of the form $p(T)$, where $p(T)=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}p_iT^i$ is any polynomial of degree $<N$:
$$
p(T)=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
p_0&p_1&p_2&p_3&\cdots&p_{N-1}\\
p_{N-1}&p_0&p_1&p_2&\cdots&p_{N-2}\\
p_{N-2}&p_{N-1}&p_0&p_1&\cdots&p_{N-3}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
p_2&p_3&p_4&p_5&\cdots&p_1\\
p_1&p_2&p_3&p_4&\cdots&p_0
\end{array}\right).
$$

The eigenvalues of circulant matrices are fully known. The eigenvalues of $T$ are the $N$th roots of unity, $\zeta_N^\ell=e^{2\pi i k/N}$ for $\ell=0,1,\ldots,N-1$, and the eigenvalues of $p(T)$ are then simply $\lambda_\ell=p(\zeta_N^\ell), \ell=0,1,\ldots,N-1$.
This is because powers of $T$ all commute with each other, and they are all simultaneously diagonalizable, so we can just add the eigenvalues of the terms together. They share the eigenvectors with $T$, but I leave it to you as an exercise to find them. You may(?) have seen the eigenvectors in a context of discrete Fourier Transforms, if that happens to be in your repertoire.

The determinant of your matrix is the product of its eigenvalues
$$
\begin{aligned}
\det A&=\prod_{\ell=0}^{N-1}(1+k[\zeta_N^\ell-1+\zeta_N^{-\ell}])\\
&=\prod_{\ell=0}^{N-1}(1-k+2k\cos\frac{2\pi\ell}N).
\end{aligned}
$$